# What is the python data type for Google Bigquery's TIMESTAMP?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm loading data into Google's BigQuery using the google-cloud-python library as found here:

http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Part of it involves checking the data types of the data I'm importing to ensure they match the datatypes in the schema for the target table. To do this I convert a python object type to the GBQ equivalent:

```
import datetime 

def convert_type_to_bigquery(object_type):
    if isinstance(object_type, str):
        return 'STRING'
    elif isinstance(object_type, bytes):
        return 'BYTES'
    elif isinstance(object_type, int):
        return 'INTEGER'
    elif isinstance(object_type, float):
        return 'FLOAT'
    elif isinstance(object_type, bool):
        return 'BOOLEAN'
    elif isinstance(object_type, datetime.date):
        return 'DATE'
    elif isinstance(object_type, datetime.time):
        return 'TIME'
    elif isinstance(object_type, datetime.datetime):
        return 'DATETIME'
    elif isinstance(object_type, ???):
        return 'TIMESTAMP'
    else:
        return None
```

I can find equivalents for all but the `TIMESTAMP` type. Is there an equivalent I can use in `isinstance()`?

Comment: Have you looked at the pandas-gbq package? It handles a lot of this your checking for you

Comment: I haven't but I shall. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do `print(type(object_type))` with the `TIMESTAMP` object to be sure but, according to this [github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/11e310ab9f63f06252ff2b9ada201fd8c11ce06c/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/dbapi/types.py), it looks like it's just `datetime.datetime`:

```
...
Date = datetime.date
Time = datetime.time
Timestamp = datetime.datetime
...
```

I must say, the main reason I wanted to add an answer was to point out a common error with `ìsinstance(...)`. This won't work since `bool` is an instance of `int`:

```
elif isinstance(object_type, int):
    return 'INTEGER'
elif isinstance(object_type, float):
    return 'FLOAT'
elif isinstance(object_type, bool):
    return 'BOOLEAN'
```

Look at this example:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```

You need to use `elif type(object_type) is int:` or place the check for `bool` first.

Comment: in Python3.8:  ```>>> isinstance(True, bool)
True
>>> isinstance(1, bool)
False```

Comment: @iowatt not sure what you are trying to point out but it's the same in any python3 version. The check you need to test is `isinstance(True, int)`.